# I wan't to create an web page to buy new user license for my salesforce App but outside the LMO?

Tags: licenses, userlicense, lma, lmo

I'm not sure how I can do it and respect security because it look like usualy people do it in salesforce apex visual force page?

I want to use an external web site done in .net for being able to change it regularly an easily.

How I can make people buy outside and update LMO from outside salesfoce by calling the REST API?

I'm able to call a web service to update informations but how I can authenticate my customer with is org and app in the LMO?

Normally people will use user and password from inside Salesforce but i'm outside salesforce and I could do a custom REST method to authenticate or Oauth? Does this will pass security review?